# operation on all numbers iwthin a text

Tags: python, regex, replace, numbers

I would like to **multiply all numbers within a text** file by the same factor. I don't really know where to begin with (I am currently trying the re replace method but that doesn't seem to do the trick). Please help!

Comment: Use `re.sub()` with a function as the replacement. The function can do `return str(int(match) * 2)`

Comment: Ok thanks, but I'm not sure how to do it. Would it be possible to give an example? (What do you mean by match?) Thanks

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Python 3.9  coding

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regexp that matches numbers, and a function replacement. The function should parse the matched string as a number, multiply it by 2, then return that as a string.

```
import re

def int_or_float(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return float(s)

text = "Blah blah 3 foo bar -15 xxx 124.3"
newtext = re.sub(r'-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?', lambda m: str(int_or_float(m.group(0)) * 2), text)
print(newtext)
# Output: Blah blah 6 foo bar -30 xxx 248.6
```

Answer (score 0):

With this:

`Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\d$");` you get all the numbers.

So just multiply then.

(If you want to put them back to the text just get the index of these numbers).

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: C#. The author of the post doesn't mentioned the language of what he is using.